# Outlook 2010 calendar appointment - format text as HTML

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, text-formatting, appointments

Is there any way to create a calendar appointment or meeting request in Outlook 2010 and format the text as HTML (rather than Rich Text/RTF which seems to be the default)?  When I create a new email message I get the option to change the text format:

[image: Outlook New Mail Message, Format Text as HTML]

But I don't seem to get this option when creating calendar appointments..

The Rich Text format seems to cause a few problems, e.g. when recipients reply the From/To/Subject fields formatting isn't as nice as when replying to an HTML message, and a bigger issue is that images/screenshots pasted into the body of the appointment cause the size to balloon.

Comment: Technically it should be able to support it (according to MS' API help files regarding the Calendar and Appointment items in Exchange), but it looks like MS just hasn't chosen to support anything but RTF in the Outlook UI for Calendars, Appointments, etc. for some reason.  Now that you've pointed it out, I'd be interested to see if I could make one programmatically via EWS, and see how Outlook handles it, but that doesn't help your plight any unfortunately. Have an upvote. :)